# DFA for the set of strings of 0’s and 1’s such that there are two 0’s separated by a number of positions that is a multiple of 4

Tags: formal-languages, finite-automata

I've being trying to understand this statement for quite a long time especially the "number of positions" part, but i can't seem to interpret it correctly.What i understand is that the statement means that there should be two 0's seperated by a number of symbols that are multiples of 4 i-e (0 , 4 , 8 , 16...), according to my understanding the string "01110", should not be in the language as the 0's are seperated by three 1's which is clearly not a multiple of 4, but the solution to the problem i've seen here:

https://www.google.com.pk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjxtfzov9jWAhXGJ8AKHfP6D6gQFggmMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ics.uci.edu%2F~goodrich%2Fteach%2Fcs162%2Fhw%2FHW1Sols.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2XrD6v28VSz30I7l5jvdLd

[image]

Suggests that "01110" is in the language.

Can someone please help me with understanding what the question statement means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interpretation is correct. It looks to me like the "solution" is wrong (and the solution isn't strictly a DFA).

Assuming you don't mind an NFA (getting a DFA is a bit fiddly, but obviously doable), you can fix the solution by removing the $(q_{4},0) \rightarrow q_{5}$ transition, and adding $(q_{5}, 0) \rightarrow q_{5}$ and $(q_{5}, 1) \rightarrow q_{5}$ transitions.

After some fiddling, it seems like a minimal DFA for this has 23 states... not so much fun.

Comment: In NFA, how can we remove $(q_4,0)\to q_5$ because after receiving $0$ in $q_4$, it goes to the accepting state

Comment: the part that I don't understand is that whether the automaton stops after having first two $0$'s separated by mod $4$ $1$'s or it continues until the entire string is checked by it.